# Host Wordpress (using docker) with different IP address

Tags: wordpress, docker, ip

I am looking to host wordpress (through docker) with an IP address that is different than the host machine. So instead of accessing wordpress from my local address 192.xxx.xxx.xxx, I want to be able to pick an address to be able to access it from. any help with this?

Comment: Check out this: https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/container-networking/#ip-address-and-hostname

Answer (score 0):

You have to create a custom network like in the followinf example (which uses **docker compose**):

```yaml
version: '3.5'

services:
    portainer:
        image: portainer/portainer-ce:latest
        container_name: portainer
        ports:
          - "8000:9000"
        networks:
          internal:
            ipv4_address: 172.2.0.2
        volumes:
          - portainer:/data
          - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
        restart: always

networks:
  internal:
    driver: bridge
    ipam:
      driver: default
      config:
        - subnet: 172.2.0.0/16

    portainer:
        name: portainer_data
```